# Keyboard And TextView's InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview, inputaccessoryview

first:

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = bar;
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

later:

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = nil;
[textView reloadInputViews];
[textView resignFirstResponder];
[self.view addSubView:bar];
```

bar is the inputAccessoryView. 
It's not be added to self.view. 
How to achieve it?

Comment: Please split your word apart to make it readable.

Comment: @KChen can you show that in code.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr see it again

Comment: @KChen Is `bar` view in xib or creating it programatically?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr programatically

Comment: @KChen so try creating `bar` view again after `textview.inputAccessoryView = nil;` and then add to `self.view`

Comment: @kChen try to other key board notifications like UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I have some state on the the bar. If so, it should do a lot of work?

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali When I use textview.inputAccessoryView = nil and use [textview reloadinputviews], I can see an animation. I think the bar it's not remove before we can see it. I do the addsubview work after a delay of 1 second, it can achieve. But I don't want to do it after 1 second.